# Connecting jsp to database

Tags: jsp

I have designed a jsp page from which i am passing the field values to another jsp page.. In this page, I want to store the values in a database and display appropriate messages according to success or failure in this page. Everything seems to work correctly except that the data does not get inserted into the database and no error maessages are displayed.

---

students.jsp

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="students_final.jsp">
  Student name:<input type="text" value="" name="name">
  Reg no:<input type="text" value="" name="regno">
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

---

students_final.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.*" import="java.sql.*"%>

<% 
  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdbase";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "passwd");  

    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String regno=request.getParameter("regno");

    "INSERT INTO `schooldatabase`.`test` (`name`) VALUES ('" + name + "');";
    Statement st= connection.createStatement();
    int count=st.executeUpdate(strquery);

    /*ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(strquery);*/
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("Could not connect");
  }
%>
```

I know there is a very silly mistake. Please help me find it !!

Comment: Your first mistake is adding scriptlet code to a JSP.  Learn JSTL.

Comment: But i guess we can use scriptlets inside a jsp page...

Comment: You can, but you should not.  This is 1998 technology.  No one writes JSPs this way anymore.

Comment: I understand that i should be using beans and servlets.. But i just want to know what my fault here is ??

Answer (score 1):

Try committing the transaction.  It may be that auto commit is false.

You should be using PreparedStatement.  This is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

You don't close any of your resources, so this app won't be running for long if you ever get it to work.

Comment: I tried using the above script. Nothing gets inserted. But I am able to insert values by opening the mysql command line..

Comment: Yup, I get it.  Did you try committing?

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schooldatabase";
```

If I'm not mistaken you ran this query in MySQL and as far as I can tell "schooldatabase" is the database name and "test" is the table in it. Also

```
String query = "INSERT INTO test ('name') VALUES ("+name+")";
int count = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT INTO `schooldatabase`.`test` (`name`) VALUES ('" + name + "');";

assign this to a variable